# Conveying Unknown Locations on a Map

Tags: usability, design-patterns, filter, info-visualisation, maps

Scenario:

You have a list of machines with some missing location data due to privacy restrictions or incomplete information.
You offer both a list view and a map view for users to explore these machines.
Users can filter the list and map by area.

Challenges:

How do you show on the map that there might be more machines in a specific area even if their exact locations are unknown?
How do you handle a situation where a user zooms in on a single machine displayed on the map, but you know there might be additional unknown machines in the vicinity?

[image: Map Filtering with Examples]

Comment: How does the unknown serves to a purpose? Maybe I'm not getting this right but this sounds too mystical, same as saying "there is a chest of gold hidden somewhere in your city, which may o may not exist". Mi point is: data-visualization is about DATA, not the possibility of it

Comment: @Devin Imagine you have five devices but only two have special trackers which allow you show them on a map. If you are looking at a map, would you want to tell you, you only have two devices or would you prefer to see the ones with trackers and still be informed you have three out there, just no trackers yet to place them on map.